# with nginx change url being sent to passenger

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

We are currently using passenger and nginx to deploy multiple rails apps to a server.
Right now we are in a situation where we have one app that has a public URL, but we are working to standardize these urls a bit. So we want to move it, but the short term we have to keep it at both URL's, so we can't update rails to know to ignore the part of the URL below.

Old configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name someapp.somedomain.com;

    root /var/www/someapp/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location /50x.html {
            root html;
    }
}
```

new block we are trying to add:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.somedomain.com;

     location /someapp {
        alias /var/www/someapp/public;
        passenger_base_uri /;
        passenger_app_root /var/www/someapp;
        passenger_document_root /var/www/someapp/public;
        passenger_enabled on;

    }
}
```

The end goal is that we keep both of these. However the issue is that when we try to go to the URL outlined in the new block, rails sees the `/someapp/` in the URL and does not understand where to route to.
We tried adding `rewrite ^/someapp(/.*)$ $1 last;` however that caused it to leave the location block and not go to the right app.
I need to find some way of changing the URL that is passed to rails for the short term, until we can remove the old URL completely and update rails.
For this specific app we don't need to worry about what Url's rails may generate.

End Goal:
Basically the plan is that both of these blocks should exist in some form. The same rails application is reachable at both `someapp.somedomain.com` and `api.somedomain.com\someapp`

Comment: Please describe your problem and end state better. "Nginx does not understand where to route it" doesn't make sense - you've just not configured it for your desired end state. You haven't said what you want your end state to be - do you want that location block to server files from the disk, proxy to something, etc. Make it easy for people to understand your question and help you.

Comment: I updated it so I included what the end goal was. However for the routing part. That is rails. With the second block rails will see the requested URL as having `\someapp\` in it, so it does not understand where to route it since that does not map to anything in the application. However in the first block it does not see that since that is not part of the URL. Rails has a way to tell it that it is at `\someapp\` but then that breaks the old URL.